# Midpoints of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $O_1,O_2,O_3$ and $O_4$ be the midpoints of a quadrilateral. It is true that $\vec{O_1O_3}=\text{...}\vec{AC}+\text{...}\vec{BD}.$

> $$\vec{O_1O_3}=\dfrac12\vec{AC}+\dfrac12\vec{BD}$$

[image]

It is known that $\vec{O_1O_3}=\dfrac12\left(\vec{AD}+\vec{BC}\right).$ How can I continue?

Comment: "*It is known that...*" Then just apply that to quadrilateral $ABDC$.

Comment: @dxiv, I have obviously applied it.

Comment: If you used it, then there was no question left to ask. The whole proof can be written as: $\text{"it is known that }$ $\vec{O_1O_3}=\dfrac12\left(\vec{AD}+\vec{BC}\right)$ $\text{ in quadrilateral ABCD, so writing the equality for quadrilateral ABDC gives }$ $\vec{O_1O_3}=\dfrac12\left(\vec{AC}+\vec{BD}\right) \text{q.e.d."}$. Note that $ABCD$ and $ABDC$ have the same midpoints $O_1, O_3$.

Comment: @dxiv, I don’t understand you at all. $ABDC$ and $ABCD$ is the same quadrilateral. The midsegment of every quadrilateral is equal to the half-sum of the vectors determined by the other two sides. There isn’t anything about the diagonals of the quadrilateral.

Comment: Review the proof you have for the "*it is known*" part. There is nothing in it about any particular quadrilateral. It's a relation that holds for $4$ arbitrary points $A,B,C,D$ and the midpoints of two disjoint pairs. The same relation holds if, for example, $A,B,C,D$ were the vertices of a tetrahedron instead of $4$ points in the plane. Since the relation holds for any $4$ points, write it down while replacing $A \to A, B \to B, C \to D, D \to C$, then you get the new relation that you want to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\vec{O_1O_3}=\vec{O_1A}+\vec{AC}+\vec{CO_3}$

$\vec{O_1O_3}=\vec{O_1B}+\vec{BD}+\vec{DO_3}$

Add the two and use $\vec{O_1A}+\vec{O_1B}=0$ and $\vec{CO_3}+\vec{DO_3}=0$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help